# Looking for Java based open source business rule engine for XML data validation

Tags: java, xml, rule-engine

I'm looking for Java based open source business rule engine for XML data validation in enterprise application. I have following XML (simplified for example sake)

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeId>1</EmployeeId>
        <FirstName>Dave</Firstname>
        <MiddleName>M</MiddleName>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <!--
            On this field validate:
            - Minimum base salaray is at least 50000
            - Maximum base salaray does not exceeds 100000          
        -->
        <BaseSalary>54000</BaseSalary>
        <!--
            On this field validate:
            - Maximum bonuses does not exceeds 10000            
        -->
        <Bonuses>2000</Bonuses>
        <!--
            On this field validate:
            - Maximum commission does not exceeds 50000         
        -->
        <Commission>4000</Commission>
        <!--
            On this field validate:
            - BaseSalary + Bonuses + Commission = TotalComp         
        -->
        <TotalComp>60000</TotalComp>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeId>2</EmployeeId>
        <FirstName>John</Firstname>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <!--
            On this field validate:
            - Minimum base salaray is at least 50000
            - Maximum base salaray does not exceeds 100000          
        -->
        <BaseSalary>60000</BaseSalary>
        <!--
            On this field validate:
            - Maximum bonuses does not exceeds 10000            
        -->
        <Bonuses>4000</Bonuses>
        <!-- Since Commission tag doesn't exists commission validation should not trigger -->
        <!--
            On this field validate:
            - BaseSalary + Bonuses + Commission = TotalComp         
        -->
        <TotalComp>64000</TotalComp>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeId>3</EmployeeId>
        <FirstName>Thomas</Firstname>
        <MiddleName>L</MiddleName>
        <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
        <!--
            On this field validate:
            - Minimum base salaray is at least 50000
            - Maximum base salaray does not exceeds 100000          
        -->
        <BaseSalary>60000</BaseSalary>
        <!--
            On this field validate:
            - Maximum bonuses does not exceeds 10000            
        -->
        <Bonuses>5000</Bonuses>
        <!--
            On this field validate:
            - Maximum commission does not exceeds 50000         
        -->
        <Commission>4000</Commission>
        <!--
            On this field validate:
            - BaseSalary + Bonuses + Commission = TotalComp         
        -->
        <TotalComp>69000</TotalComp>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

The following is validation requirement:

- Rule is tag based (eg employee #2 is missing Commission tag and there for no validations related with Commission data should be triggered)
- Multiple rules can be attached to specific xml tag
- Rule can validate multiple xml fields
- Rules can be added/removed dynamically during runtime
- The XML file size is anywhere between 100MB to 1GB so loading everything in the memory is not an option.
- Some type of validation session to keep track of previous data/validation result (eg When validating employee #3, rules should have access to data/validation result from employee #1 and #2)

Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: XSD 1.1 processor is what you need. Take a look at Xerces-J .2.12.2

Answer (score 0):

You have pretty much described the capabilities of Schematron, with one exception: Schematron doesn't do streaming, so you may run out of memory. (There are multiple Schematron implementations, but that's a detail.)

Some of the key ideas of Schematron were incorporated into XSD 1.1, and some XSD 1.1 engines are capable of streaming - provided that your validation rules don't require comparing the first element in the document with the last! There are two Java-based XSD 1.1 implementations, Xerces and Saxon - the latter is my company's product.

Comment: I could see using Xerces2 to execute validation as SAX or StAX parses along the XML. However, one information that I left out is that these rules need to be add/remove during runtime.

Comment: You mean you want to change the rules in the middle of parsing? Well, that dramatically changes the ball-game, and basically means you're going to have to write it yourself.

Comment: Oh no not middle of parsing. If there is a change in the rule configuration, the change will take affect for new XML.